# Riiddle me this

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> You cannot see me, but I am within everything and everyone,
>   I will never die and I have been with time since long as I can remember.
>   I am and will ever be what is left when everything dies.

**What am I?**

Comment: Is the double "i" in the title a typo?

Comment: @SMR it miight be :)

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> space ?

I believe this is quite self-explanatory. It is "with time" since the

> big bang (see [spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime))

You cannot see it because

> you only see what is emitting, reflecting, absorbing or dispersing light. For instance you can see the blue sky, the stars, ... but you cannot see space (just as you cannot see time) ; you can only have a knowledge of variation with space (and/or time), i.e., two different objects at the same time are in different positions in space.

Answer (score 3):

I guess its :

> Energy.

You cannot see me, but I am within everything and everyone,

> Self explanatory. There is always some energy within everything whether in very small amount or of any kind but is there.

I will never die and I have been with time since long as I can remember.I am and will ever be what is left when everything dies.

> Energy can neither be created nor be destroyed.

Comment: Energy can be *generated*.

Comment: It's just converted from one form to other. I guess generation means the same. @Astralbee

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> **ever**?

You cannot see me, but I am within everything and everyone,

> "Ever" is a concept, and thus impossible to see. It is within **ever**ything and **ever**yone, though.

I will never die and I have been with time since long as I can remember.

> Because you are, well, ever.

I am and will ever be what is left when everything dies.

> You are "ever", and will "ever" be, even after **ever**ything has died.

Answer (score 2):

For the religious, the answer is

> $\dagger$ **Lord God; Father of Heaven**. $\dagger$ Also, @ManojKumar said it could include **spirit / soul**.

---

But putting that aside, could it also be

> **Nothing**?

`You cannot see me, but I am within everything and everyone.`

> You cannot see *nothing*${}^1$, but it is within **everything and everyone** (just grab the letters $\verb|n|$ and $\verb|o|$, and then combine it with $\verb|thing|$). 
>   <sub>${}^1$@Bass commented below that this is not true if you are pretty much blind; this is the only flaw in my answer, perhaps.</sub>

`I will never die and have been with time since as long as I can remember.`

> Eventually, **something** will die; **nothing** will never die. The latter part of the sentence is fairly self-explanatory.

`I am and will ever be what is left when everything dies.`

> When **everything** dies, there is **nothing** left.

---

`What am I?`

> **Nothing**?

<sub><sup>Gurer Vf N Tbq</sup></sub>

Comment: It can also be Fcvevg/Fbhy(ROT13).

Comment: A blind person would definitely be able to see that.

Comment: @Bass not necessarily, unless you are *fully* blind.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be

> an atom

You cannot see me, but I am within everything and everyone

> Atoms are the basic building block of all matter

I will never die and I have been with time since long as I can remember.

> Atoms can decay but do not go out of existence (so I guess technically they don't "die"?)

I am and will ever be what is left when everything dies.

> When something dies, its atoms are recycled.

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> Ether

As,

> It is ever pervasive, invisible, was existing time immemorial and would be there in future as well !

Comment: Except it's been proven to not exist. It also starts with an "A" followed by the rest as is

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are:

> Energy.
>
>  (this answer has already been given but I didn't agree with the explanations)

You cannot see me

> Energy is not visible, until it gives rise to physical matter.

but I am within everything and everyone

> We are all composed of physical matter, or atoms. Within every atom is energy.

I will never die

> When atoms are destroyed the energy is released

and I have been with time since long as I can remember.

> The physical universe was created from energy (no matter where you believe that energy came from). It is generally accepted that the universe had a beginning and that event was an infinite source of energy giving rise to matter, or a source of infinitely dense matter releasing that energy.
>
>  As time is connected to matter, it is argued that time as we know it only began with the physical universe.

I am and will ever be what is left when everything dies.

> As stated, when physical matter is destroyed, the energy is released. This is what makes atomic energy possible.

Comment: Why did this get a downvote? $(+1)$

Comment: @user477343 Probably because it was already posted!